# How can I reset the password on a PostgreSQL database on my machine?

Tags: postgresql, password

I installed PostgreSQL on my Windows 7 machine a few weeks ago. Now I would like to create a database with `createdb mydb` but I don't remember the password.

Is there anyway to reset the password? I have access to the Administrator account on my machine. Or do I have to uninstall PostgreSQL and then reinstall it again?

How can I reset the password on a PostgreSQL database on my machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit pg_hba.conf to allow access without a password, use "trust". Restart postgresql and you can access PostgreSQL without the usage of a password. Alter your password to something you can remember :) , edit pg_hba.conf again and reload pg_hba.conf.

The [Ubuntu-manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/postgresql.html) has a description about this issue as well.

Comment: Where in the `pg_hba.conf` should I put `trust`? do you have an example?

Comment: See the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html